# What test to use for same group but different measurements?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a non-normally distributed data for example duration of reaching, lifting, holding and releasing from 30 subjects. I am trying to see if the duration of reaching and lifting is shorter than the holding and releasing. I am not sure what kind of test to use for this kind of analysis.

I understand for between different groups (e.g. healthy and stroke patients), where I will use wilcoxon rank sum test, but for same subject group, I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). That test is for paired data of the type you want to test, whereas the confusingly similarly named test [Wilcoxon rank sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) is usually called the Mann-Whitney U test to avoid confusion, and is a test for independent (not paired) variables.

Comment: Wicoxon signed-rank test for paired samples. I read somewhere saying that "the criterion is something that makes pairs of values at least somewhat positively dependent, while unpaired values are not dependent".

First measures (reaching and lifting duration) is not dependent on second one (holding and releasing). So i don't know if my data can be considered as 'paired' samples?

Comment: What makes the data paired is that you have the same subjects for "reaching and lifting" as well as "holding and releasing." That means that using Wilcoxon signed-rank testing would tell you whether "reaching and lifting" is different than "holding and releasing." Since you already know they are different physical measurements, the question as to whether they are different temporally is only really questioning if the times are different for what you already know are different things. I would be surprised if the answer were "no" no difference.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Actually the duration for lifting is shorter than releasing for healthy subjects but no difference for stroke subjects. Thanks for your explanation, I just need to be sure on how are the data can be considered 'paired' for me to use signed-rank test.

Comment: The data are literally data pairs. Typically, this means two columns of numbers, with each column representing the results of that column's test with the same number of entries in each column and where each row indicates the results for the same subject.